# Avoid page break between section title and included subsections

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, include

When I apply the following code, I have a page break between the `\section{*}` and the `\include{chapters/*.tex}` (the chapters are composed of subsection). I would like to have no page break between the section title and the subsection title.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hcmut-report}
\usepackage{codespace}
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath,amssymb,gensymb,textcomp}
\usepackage{array,multicol,multirow,siunitx,tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption,float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mwe}

% Custom commands
% Remove if unneeded
\newcommand*\mean[1]{\bar{#1}}

\ocoursename{*}
\oreporttype{*}
\title{*}
\oauteurs{*}
\reportlayout%

\begin{document}

\coverpage%

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\section{Site d'étude}
\include{chapters/Site.tex}
\section{Hydrologie}
\include{chapters/Hydrologie.tex}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs}
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

I have also a cover page, but I guess it is not necessary to add the code here.

Comment: `\include` always has a page break, put `\section` in the included file, or use `\input` not `\include`

Comment: highest score question on the whole site https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I did not know about `\input`. Everything is good now.